# Blueman manager wont start. New to linux

Tags: antix

So I've just recently installed antiX linux on my old mac mini. I'm completely new to linux as a whole, and am currently trying to pair bluetooth headphones to my device as my aux port is broken. I'm at the moment, unable to start my bluetooth manager.